# DB table refactoring

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, nhibernate

Hi I'm using ms2005 for a simple calendaring system.
We have three 'legacy' tables: Groups, Units and Staff.

I need to give each record in the tables a unique identifier (carrying across all 3 tables).

What would be best way to approach this? I am using NHibernate and was was wondering whether that could do it for me.

Anyway, any nods in the right direction much appreciated.

Comment: It would help to add some more explanation to this question - sample layouts of all 3 tables (with just the important columns), and more explanation of what you mean by "carrying across all 3 tables".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual practice is to create a surrogate primary key on each table using an int with IDENTITY(1,1).

If you need a unique values across systems then use a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column (GUID).

Comment: Maybe; but see my following request for clarification. Use the IDENTITY column; only use UNIQUEIDENTIFIER if you understand what that is, when to use it, and why. Which is unlikely, given your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the same identifier shouldn't appear in more than one table? That would be a fishy assertion that would suggest that more discussion is needed.

It would be a "Bad Smell", in a refactoring sense.